# How to store a file in google app by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

Hi. How to store a file in google app by using jQuery. I'm using the plugin given [here](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). But it is not working.
My HTML code is:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="<%= blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/fileloadupload") %> method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

In my project, when I store the file in google app, I'm storing the blobkey in my database simultaneously. I'm using servlets and jsp. Please help me how can I store a file in google app by using jQuery.

Comment: hi any one help me how to upload file in google app by using jquey please help me urgent.

Comment: Have you read this - http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/05/upload-all-file-types-to-any-google.html ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HtmlService to create an HTML form.  The Submit button will call a gs function.  In this example it will upload to your Google Docs.

HTML File:

```
<html>
<form id='myForm'>
<input name='myFile' type='file'><br>
<input type='button' value="Upload" onclick='google.script.run.uploadFile(this.parentNode)'>
</form>
<html>
```

gs File:

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html').evaluate();
}

function uploadFile(theForm){
  var file = theForm.myFile;
  DocsList.createFile(file);
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the replay but when i upload the file on that time i want to show the progress bar if don't mine please send me the total code ..it's urgent....and i upload only csv files ....